# SQLite3 database opens but doesn't show table data in Android emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to view a single table data from android emulator sqlite shell. It shows the database is there, but when I run a query on it, I get the error

"Error: no such table: note". Here is the output

```
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /data/data/myapp.barcode/databases/barcodedb.db
1    temp
sqlite> select * from note;
select * from note;
Error: no such table: note
```

I have pulled the database file from DDMS perspective, and shows the concerned table with all rows. I have tried to open the shell while app is running, then quitting the app and running shell command, but no change in error message. Any clues, as how I might be able to open, update the table from shell?

Comment: Have you done a 'Create Table note ...' command yet on your database?

Comment: Yes James, this whole database is created by a DatabaseHelper, and even rows are inserted, updated by the app.

Comment: I came across this issue some days back, and using a db.beginTransaction() before and db.commitTransaction() after a DB table create solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Type .tables and verify that table note exists while in the sqlite shell. See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) for a sqlite reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies, I have figured out what I was doing wrong. I was referring to the wrong database i.e. barcodedb.db previously created, while android was populating the new database barcodedb with no extension.

Answer (score 0):

If .tables shows nothing, it means your database is empty.

As you mention an error culd be selecting wrong database file.

In order to select correct database you can list all files inside databases folder.

```
$ls -la
```

then look for database name and checking the size. For example(attached image) there are 2 files ATC_MOVIL_DB and ATC_MOVIL_DB.db, the correct one would be ATC_MOVIL_DB because of it size.

[image]